# Como coger una foto con Picasso y la api de nasa APOD KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

Estoy intentado coger una imagen de la api de nasa APOD y meterla en un imageView, lo he hecho antes con recycler y diferentes datos pero al hacerlo con solo una imagen no se hacerlo sin crear un adapter

Tengo una interfaz

```
interface ApiService {

    @GET
suspend fun getDatosNasa(@Url url: String): Response<ListaNasaGson>
}
```

Una Data class

```
data class NasaGson(
    @SerializedName("hdurl") var url: String,
    @SerializedName("title") var title: String
)

data class ListaNasaGson(
    @SerializedName("apod")var listaNasaGson: List<NasaGson>
)
```

E intento coger la imagen asi

```
    private fun imagen() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val llamada = getRetrofit().create(ApiService::class.java).getDatosNasa("?key=$KEY")
            val datos = llamada.body() //BODY PAL HTML COGER SOLO CON EL INTERIOR Y NO CABEZERAS
            //DATOS PA METER EN RECICLER HAY Q HACERLO EN EL HILO PRINCIPAL
            runOnUiThread {
                if (llamada.isSuccessful) {
                    val datos2 = datos?.listaNasaGson ?: emptyList()
                    datosList.addAll(datos2)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@Contador, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Me sale siempre el error del toast

este es mi adaptador de las fotos

```
class AdapterFotos(private val lista: List<NasaGson>): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterFotos.ViewHolder>() {
    class ViewHolder(v: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        val binding = ActivityContadorBinding.bind(v)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contador, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = lista[position]
        holder.binding.txtTitulo.text = item.title.toString()
        Picasso.get().load(item.url).resize(150, 130).centerCrop().into(holder.binding.imagen)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return lista.count()
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir cuál es el error que te devuelve?  Puedes usar el Okhttp interceptor para comprobarlo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal es que no estas definiendo una llave correcta para poder consultar el API, debes reemplazar el valor $KEY por una llave vàlida, de esta forma podràs realizar la peticiòn correctamente:

```
        val llamada = getRetrofit().create(ApiService::class.java).getDatosNasa("?key="+ Apikey)
        ...
        ...
            if (llamada.isSuccessful) {
                val datos2 = datos?.listaNasaGson ?: emptyList()
                datosList.addAll(datos2)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@Contador, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

---

Estos son los datos que puedes definir en la peticiòn, obviamente `api_key` es esencial:

> Para devolver un APOD, realice una solicitud GET a
> https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod. Si bien los siguientes 4
> parámetros de URL son opcionales, es casi seguro que sus solicitudes
> necesitarán un par de ellos:
>
> - `api_key`: el uso de una clave API le permite realizar hasta 1000 solicitudes por hora. Si no establece uno, alcanzará los límites de
>   cuota con bastante rapidez. Puede obtener una completando el
>   formulario de clave de API simple, luego se le enviará una clave de
>   API por correo electrónico en unos minutos.
> - `date`: Esta es la fecha para la que desea devolver el APOD (en formato AAAA-MM-DD), si no se establece ninguno, se devolverá el
>   último APOD. Consulte la sección "Limitaciones" para obtener más
>   información al respecto.
> - `start_date` y `end_date`: esta es una alternativa a la fecha y devuelve una matriz de todos los APOD dentro del rango.
> - `hd`: especifica si la URL HD de la imagen debe devolverse junto con una URL de calidad normal y debe establecerse en verdadero o falso.
>   Sin embargo, la API no parece seguir siempre este parámetro y, a
>   veces, devuelve la URL HD incluso si no la has solicitado.
>
> Un ejemplo de URL completo es:
>
> `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&date=2021-12-17;`